# How to use a function that returns an UIBezierPath to start an animation?

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, uibezierpath

I've used coreAnimation before but not as individual functions but instead something like this:

```
   let v1 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 50, height: 50))
    v1.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    view.addSubview(v1)

    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "cornerRadius")
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    animation.fromValue = v1.layer.cornerRadius
    animation.toValue = v1.bounds.width/2
    animation.duration = 3
    v1.layer.add(animation, forKey: "cornerRadius")
```

Right now I'm trying to use a function that returns a UIBezierPath but am unsure how to use it properly

```
 func circlePathWithCenter(center: CGPoint, radius: CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath {
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath()
    circlePath.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi, endAngle: -CGFloat.pi/2, clockwise: true)
    circlePath.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi/2, endAngle: 0, clockwise: true)
    circlePath.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat.pi/2, clockwise: true)
    circlePath.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: CGFloat.pi/2, endAngle: CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
    circlePath.close()
    return circlePath
  }
```

I've tried creating a custom CALayer but get the warning

> Result of call to 'circlePathWithCenter(center:radius:)' is unused

Here is the code for calling the function in the viewController

```
 @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    let point = CGPoint(x:self.view.frame.origin.x, y: 100)

//morphLayer is the name of the custom CALayer
        let newLayer = morphLayer(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 100))
        newLayer.circlePathWithCenter(center: point, radius: 100) // warning here
      }
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are receiving a warning because the function `circlePathWithCenter` returns a `UIBezierPath` but the line responsible for this function call is not using the return value anywhere

```
newLayer.circlePathWithCenter(center: point, radius: 100)
```

If that is the desired workflow and you don't want to store the value anywhere, you can just assign the return value to an `_`. This tells the compiler that you know there is a return value but you are not interested in it. The syntax for that is as simple as

```
_ = newLayer.circlePathWithCenter(center: point, radius: 100)
```

However, if you want to use the return value, then you'll have to store it in a variable and use it accordingly.